# Bootstrap data table not responsive in small devices

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am using a bootstrap template for my admin panel. my issue is in responsiveness of data table. Data tables loss its responsiveness in  small display devices.
[data table mobile version[image: ][1]]

Comment: This is a general issue with all bootstrap3 usage, it is not mobile first. In bootstrap 4 there is much more focus on small devices, and dataTables seems to prepare for bootstrap4.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'table-responsive'

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```